# Why Should We Use wp_clear_scheduled_hook and What it Does?

Tags: actions, wp-cron

I am new to cron job.

After reading  [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) article I was able to run a function every hour using `wp_schedule_event`.

There is a quote on "Don't forget to clean the scheduler on deactivation" in that page.

I read the documentation of `wp_clear_scheduled_hook`.

But still I could not understand why we should use `wp_clear_scheduled_hook` and what it do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you deactivate the plugin, the scheduled event will still try to run ( and fail )  unless you remove that event from the schedule using [wp_clear_scheduled_hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_clear_scheduled_hook)

Comment: Kind of lame question but if this need to be set in `register_activation_hook` and `register_deactivation_hook` sequence or just when the plugin is deactivated? On one hosting I had an issue with my plugin that WP Cron was executed once then after that it wasn't executed after getting `register_deactivation_hook` (but it was on the WP Cron list).